# Если ли справочник по PHP?

Tags: php

Если ли справочник по PHP, в котором описаны все операторы, команды и т.д., как в словаре? И где его можно найти, если существует? Например:

> abs
>
> (PHP 3, PHP 4, PHP 5)
>
> abs -- Модуль числа
>
> Описание
>
> number abs ( mixed number )
>
> Возвращает абсолютное значение number. Если number имеет тип float, возвращаемое значение также будет иметь тип float, иначе - integer.
>
> Пример 1. Пример
>
> `<?php 
> $abs = abs(-4.2); // $abs = 4.2; (double/float)
> $abs2 = abs(5);   // $abs2 = 5; (integer)
> $abs3 = abs(-5);  // $abs3 = 5; (integer)
> ?>`

и так по каждому.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть, конечно, например [php.su: Функции PHP](http://www.php.su/functions/?abs).

P.S. Если честно, я предпочитаю просто в яндексе забивать поиск типа
"команда PHP" и спокойно читать (хотя в большинстве случаев все равно на этот сайт попадаю).

Comment: или оффициальный сайт http://www.php.net, справа вверху окошко поиска "search for", ввел название функции и получил описание с примерами и высказываниями программистов о применении.
PS на английском языке

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, лучший справочник по php - это [php.net: Functions](http://php.net/abs).